# Remove colored spaces and tabs in nano on a system-wide level

Tags: linux, syntax-highlighting, nano

How can I make it so that nano doesn't highlight spaces and tabs with a color for every user on a system?  Rather than making a change in my own .nanorc file, how can I edit it so it will apply to all users?

Comment: On most linux distros, the default nano configuration file is located /etc/nanorc

Comment: @JakePsimos I was looking at that a bunch and saw the color set up section but I couldn't figure out how to do it.  I also can't seem to find anything online about this.